# Calling Native code from android NativeActivity

Tags: android, android-ndk, powervr-sgx

I am trying to learn how to use powervr insider sdk.
As soon as I open my MainActivity.java file it's extending NativeActivity and it calls it using super.onCreate().
Here is the code:

```
package com.powervr.OGLES2IntroducingPOD;

import android.app.NativeActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.Gravity;

public class MainActivity extends NativeActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void displayExitMessage(final String text) 
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        }
        });
    }
}
```

After this, my native codes start to get executed.

I want to know if there is some function defined in native cpp files which NativeActivity looks after calling super.oncreate(), or how does the whole thing happen.

Or is there any way by which we can look the sequence in which cpp files is executing apart from putting a log in every file, since I have too many cpp files and it's not practical to put a log in all files.

Comment: How about debugging to determine the sequence?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is started from the PVRShellOS.cpp file where the android_main(android_app* state) is present. this is called by the native oncreate function